# How can I get rid of the North pane line

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, web

My HTML:

```
<div class="ui-layout-center" id="inner">
    <div class="ui-layout-center">Inner Center</div>
    <div class="ui-layout-south">Inner South</div>
</div>
<div class="ui-layout-north">North</div>
<div class="ui-layout-west">West</div>
```

My javascript:

```
var myLayout;
var myLayoutInner;

$(document).ready(function(){
    myLayout = $('body').layout({ //    reference only - these options are NOT required because 'true' is the default
        closable: true, // pane can open & close
        resizable: true, // when open, pane can be resized 
        slidable: false, // when closed, pane can 'slide' open over other panes - closes on mouse-out
        livePaneResizing: true,

        north__size: '100',
        north__minSize: '100',
        north__maxSize: '100',
        north__closable: false,
        north__resizable: false,
        north__slidable: false,
        north__spacing_open: 0,
        north__spacing_closed: 0,

        west__togglerLength_closed: '100%', // toggle-button is full-width of resizer-bar
        west__spacing_closed: 20 // big resizer-bar when open (zero height)
    });

    myLayoutInner = $('#inner').layout({
        applyDefaultStyles: true,
        slidable: false, // when closed, pane can 'slide' open over other panes - closes on mouse-out
        livePaneResizing: true,
        stateManagement__enabled: true,
        //initClosed: true,
        //south__minSize: 100
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JPEaa/2/

How can I get rid of the North Pane line? I've tried...

```
north__spacing_open: 0,
north__spacing_closed: 0,
```

but they only seem to make the line thinner. I'd like it to be invisible. How can I do this?

A secondary question I have is, how can I have zero gap for the Inner Center and Inner South margin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as the North Pane Line goes, some simple CSS styling of the pane borders seems to have done the trick.

```
.ui-layout-pane {
    border: none !important;
}
```

To get rid of the spacing to the right of the pane selector, you can use

```
.ui-layout-pane-center {
    padding: 0px;
}
```

You can see a working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/JPEaa/114/.

Comment: For the Inner Center and Inner South panes I mean the margin between them and the West pane.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "the margin." Are you referring to the space to the right of the pane selector?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to get rid of the gap there.

Comment: Ok, I think I found a fix for it. I have edited my answer to include the additional CSS for the fix.

Comment: Thank you so much! How do you find which element to change so easily?

Comment: You are very welcome, rotaercz! It was actually a little bit complicated to find which class was causing the spacing issue. The approach I used was basically just utilizing the Chrome developer tools (specifically the element inspector) to select the element of interest (in this case the inner ui-layout-center pane). After this, I just looked at which classes the div was being styled with, and then I just basically went through each one of the classes and tried overriding the padding until I figured out which class was the culprit.

Comment: Also, you can take a look at the styling for the JQuery UI Layout here: http://layout.jquery-dev.net/lib/css/layout-default-latest.css.

Comment: I have edited my answer again to provide what I believe to be a more elegant solution, which requires less CSS, and fixes the border issue.

Comment: I would upthumb your comments if I could. Thanks again!